# Only the low half of EAX is zeroed? (MASM using .486 / .model flat,stdcall)

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Running the code below in VS2019, I was surprised with the fact that the register EAX is not zeroed with the instruction `xor eax, eax`.

```
_text SEGMENT
.486
.model flat,stdcall
.stack 4096

.code
main PROC
    xor eax, eax    
    ret
main ENDP
_text ENDS
END
```

P.S.: I was expecting the EAX register to be zero after the instruction `xor eax, eax`. Debugging the code with a break point in the `ret` instruction I can see in the Registers window that only AX is zeroed. Nothing happens to the bits 16-31 in EAX. In x64 the instruction `xor eax, eax` executes correctly, zeroing the entire RAX register as expected.

Comment: It certainly will be if that instruction is actually executed.  Therefore I suspect that either the instruction is not actually being executed in your test, or that you are incorrectly observing the value in eax.  What is the exact test you are doing to reach your conclusion?

Comment: @NateEldredge I actually debugged the code with a breakpoint at the `xor` instruction and then after pressing F11, I could verify that only AX is zeroed.

Comment: Could you explain how you built and ran the program?  It sounds as if there may be a 16/32 bit mode mismatch somewhere along the way.

Comment: @NateEldredge I run the code in x86 and x64 by changing the solution platform in the menu bar of Visual Studio 2019. After that, I just press F5 to debug the code.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm using VS2019 with its latest version 16.11.3.

Comment: Agreed with @Nate, this sounds like the assembler emitted a `66` operand-size prefix because it thought the instruction would execute in 16-bit mode, but then it actually executed in 32-bit mode where that prefix makes it an `xor ax,ax`, the non-default operand-size.  Does putting `.486` *after* `.model flat,stdcall` help?  I vaguely remember something about the order of those directives mattering for MASM in some other SO answer.  You could look at disassembly, and try instructions like `push eax` (probably only changes ESP by 2).

Comment: Also, to detect what mode your code is executing in, [Determine your language's version](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/139717) shows polyglot machine code that generates 16, 32, or 64 in AL depending on what mode it executes in.  You could put those bytes in `db B0h, 40h` ... directives to make sure it's independent of what mode it's assembled in.  (NASM has `bits 16` to always assemble for 16-bit mode regardless of the object-file format, but the problem here is that we don't know or trust the equivalent MASM directives.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Great, the disassembler shows that the assembler emitted a `xor ax, ax` instead of `xor eax eax` , but the `.486` after `.model` had no effect on the result. Also I can tell you that the code was run with Win32, according to the output shown on the Output window.

Comment: @PeterCordes You are also correct with regards to `66`. Looking at the address of the instruction `xor ax, ax` I see the encoding bytes used for the instruction, `66 33 C0`. Again, great answer!

Comment: According to the MASM manual, the `.*86` directive should precede the `.model` directive.

Comment: @PeterCordes Why don't you answer the question explaining in more detail, what you mentioned in the two paragraphs above [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458051/only-the-low-half-of-eax-is-zeroed-masm-using-486-model-flat-stdcall#comment122770042_69458051) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458051/only-the-low-half-of-eax-is-zeroed-masm-using-486-model-flat-stdcall#comment122770099_69458051). I would really appreciate that.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MASM, but other examples of 32-bit MASM programs that I've seen don't include a `SEGMENT` directive.  What happens if you take that out?

Comment: @Michael Could you quote the section in the MASM manual where you found this. As a matter of fact, I didn't find the string `.*86` in the alluded document.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso Page 259 in the MASM 6.1 Programmer's Manual.

Comment: @NateEldredge Great, finally the `eax` register is zeroed !!!

Comment: @Michael I didn't find anything like that in page 259. How do I check mine version of MASM?

Comment: The section is called _MASM Directives for 32-Bit Programming_. I have no idea where to find it in other verions of the manual.

Comment: @Michael Well, as I said, there is no string `.*86` in my version of the manual.

Comment: There is a description of `.486` in the [MASM reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-486?view=msvc-160) but it doesn't mention any relationship with `.model`.

Comment: If I knew anything more about MASM, I'd say so.  I know how x86 machine code works, but not how these MASM directives work, so all I could do is suggest how to investigate further, not fully answer the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comments, it seems that the `SEGMENT` directive somehow convinced the assembler that it was assembling code to be run in 16-bit mode.

In 16-bit mode, instructions operating on 32-bit registers like `eax` need a `66` operand-size prefix, so the assembler emitted `66 33 C0`.  However, the program actually ran in 32-bit mode, in which the sense of the `66` operand-size prefix is reversed: 32-bit operands are the default and `66` selects 16-bit operands.  So when the program ran, the instruction executed as `xor ax, ax` and didn't zero the high bits of `eax`.

You said that removing the `SEGMENT` directive fixed it.  I don't know exactly why it had this effect, but other examples of 32-bit MASM programs don't include this directive anyway, so it should probably never have been there at all.

Comment: How do I determine in which mode the computer is running? I believe this has to do with the link provided by @Peter Cordes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458051/only-the-low-half-of-eax-is-zeroed-masm-using-486-model-flat-stdcall#comment122770099_69458051), but that is too much advanced stuff for me to understand. But, for example, I'd like to know which directive can I use to assemble the code  in a given specific mode. How should I proceed?

Comment: The mode is set by the format and headers of your executable file, so you rely on your assembler and linker (via directives, command line options, etc) to generate an executable where it is set the right way.  I also don't know enough about MASM to explain the process completely.  But as a start, I'd say to just look for examples for either 32 or 64 bit programs, and use their directives while just changing the code.  I am not sure that modern Windows can even run programs in 16-bit mode, and you probably wouldn't want to anyway.

Comment: From the MASM documentation (emphasis mine): "The _use_ type in the `SEGMENT` directive specifies the segment word size on the 80386/486
processors. Segment word size **determines the default operand and address size of all items in a
segment**.
If you specify the `.386` or `.486` directive before the `.MODEL` directive, `USE32` is the default".  Since OP had placed the `SEGMENT` directive before `.486`/`.model` and didn't specify a size attribute, that probably gave the segment a `USE16` attribute.

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure when one would need to use the `SEGMENT` directive in a flat model program. You've got the simplified segment directives (`.code`, `.data`, `.data?` etc) which ought to be enough.

Comment: @Michael I wasn't able to find none of the stuff you mentioned [above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69458051/only-the-low-half-of-eax-is-zeroed-masm-using-486-model-flat-stdcall#comment122800007_69467699) in the current Microsoft Macro Assembler Reference.pdf.

Comment: It's in the MASM 6.1 Programmer's Guide.

Comment: @NateEldredge There is still one point that is not entirely clear to me. You wrote: "However, the program actually ran in 32-bit mode, `...`". Then why didn't the assembler correct the encoding  from `66 33 C0` to `33 C0`?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso: Because the assembler didn't *know* that the program was going to run in 32-bit mode.  It only knew what you told it from the directives, which implied 16 bit.  Once the executable is built, the bytes of machine code are whatever they are. It's not as if the system goes back and re-assembles your program every time you try to run it.

Comment: @NateEldredge At the time the assembler reads the directive `.486` it knows that the code will run in 32-bit mode. Then why  did the assembler emit the `66` operand prefix for the `xor eax, eax` instruction in the first place?

Comment: @JoãoAfonso: As Michael was saying, `.486` itself just means that the code will run on a 486, and so all 486 instructions should be accepted (32-bit registers, BSWAP, etc).  But in this program, 16-bit mode had already been selected by the `USE16` default for the `SEGMENT` directive, and `.486` coming later doesn't override that.  So you assemble for a 486 running in 16-bit mode, and that needs a `66` prefix for `xor eax, eax`.

Comment: @NateEldredge That doesn't make much sense to me. You wrote "So you assemble for a 486 running in **16-bit mode**". But in your answer above you said: "However, the program actually ran in **32-bit mode**, in which the sense of the 66 operand-size prefix is reversed:". I really can't understand whether the code run in 16, or 32 bit mode. Could you clarify?

Comment: Okay, let me say it one more time.  The particular combination of `SEGMENT` followed by `.486`, in that order, tells MASM that the program will be running in 16-bit mode.  As Michael said, `USE16` is the default for `SEGMENT` if no such directive as `.486` has been seen *previously*.  As such, the assembler emitted `66 33 C0`, which would be the correct encoding for `xor eax, eax` in 16-bit mode.  But these directives did not match the type of executable actually built, which was to run in 32-bit mode.  And in 32-bit mode, `66 33 C0` executes as `xor ax, ax`.  Which is what happened.

Comment: @JoãoAfonso: One would not normally have a USE16 segment in a program that will run in 32-bit mode, but based on the directives, that is what you accidentally told the assembler to do, and it complied.

Comment: @NateEldredge "But these directives did not match the type of executable actually built, which was to run in 32-bit mode". But how do I know in Visual Studio, whether an assembly is built to run in 16 bit or 32-bit mode?